# Facebook - Post to wall from Android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Post to wall from Android application...

```
   parameters.putString("app_id", mAppId);
   parameters.putString("picture", "http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg");
   parameters.putString("name", "Facebook Dialog");            
   parameters.putString("caption", "Reference Documentation");   
   parameters.putString("description", "Dialogs provide simple interface applications...");
   parameters.putString("message", "Facebook Dialogs are easy!");
```

I have specified above parameters and every time I am getting blank dialog (with title "Post to your wall") - and when I click on "Publish" button - it post correct values on given account... so there is no issue relate to posing parameter values to wall, but I do not know why I am getting balnk dialog!

Comment: Are you using the Facebook SDK or are you launching an Intent for the Facebook app to handle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use simple facebook sdk project it simplifies things a lot.
They have created a library project for this

https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Comment: Mention the url link specific to the problem

Comment: use developer.facbook.com . this library is discontiued